# Imformix sql 'outer' with and without parenthesis meaning

Tags: informix, outer-join

Having difficulty finding docs/ information on the '(' token and lexeme. Trying to convert to mysql, but the question is informix specific.

I want to know the syntactical difference, if any, for `from table0 outer(table1, outer table2)`
And `from table0 outer table1, outer table2`

Comment: The syntactic difference is the presence of the parentheses.  Are you more interested in the semantic difference?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation parentheses are required when the `WHERE` clause includes a relationship between the subordinate tables in the `OUTER` clause, i.e. table1 and table2 in your example.

There is further information in the [Informix-Extension Outer Joins](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=clause-informix-extension-outer-joins#ids_sqs_1035) section of the Guide to SQL: Syntax and in the section [Joins that combine outer joins](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=joins-that-combine-outer) of the Guide to SQL: Tutorial.